# GraphViz's executables not found error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-mining, graphviz, decision-tree

I wrote the following code in pycharm to build the decision tree, but I got the following error. can you help me?

***GraphViz's executables not found***

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from six import StringIO
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn import tree
import pydot
from IPython.display import Image
import pydotplus
import graphviz


dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(decisionTree1, out_file =dot_data, filled=True,
                rounded =True, special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: Have you separately downloaded graphviz as an executable? Also, what os are you running on?

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Yes, windows

Comment: Okay, thats step 1.
Is it added to the PATH environment variable?
You can check by typing environment  variables in the search bar and choosing 'edit the system env.. var..' and finding PATH in that list, and double-clicking it to open all the different paths in PATH. If you don't see the path to the graphviz executables, add it yourself on a new line.

Comment: @SamarthBhatia Unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: try running `dot -T` from your command line (cmd, not in python). If that results in an error, check the path variable by writing `PATH` on the command line, see if you can spot the GraphViz folder in there. If you've added it to `PATH` manually and it still doesn't show on the command line, I think it will take effect after a restart. 
I remember also having problems with their executable.
Also note you need to add the `.../Graphviz/bin/` folder to the path, which actually contains the executable `dot.exe`.